# An error occurred while calling o67.load: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/staging/StagingDirectoryCapable

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, airflow, amazon-emr

**The scenario is the following:**

I am trying to calculate the record count for a file in s3 location, from EMR by reading it through spark.

**This is the error I'm getting:**

while calling o67.load: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/staging/StagingDirectoryCapable.

The error is intermittent, it crops up sometimes and works fine every now and then.

Emr version used - 5.29.0

Answer (score 1):

> org/apache/hadoop/fs/staging/StagingDirectoryCapable.

That must be a class/interface exclusive to EMR; it's not in the ASF Codebase. Maybe there are classpath problems

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply, can you share a link where i can go through a more elaborate approach to this, and how can i pin point to the classpath that is creating this issue.

Comment: you will need to raise a support issue with the AWS EMR Team. their source, their homework

Comment: Yes, this is an EMR-specific class that was added to Hadoop. Are you overriding spark.executor.extraClassPath? Or if you are using an uber application jar, does it include any Hadoop classes?